# How much there exists operators of $a\in End(\mathbb{F}_p^3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-algebras

How much there exists operators of $a\in End(\mathbb{F}_p^3)$ such that a((2, -1, 3)) = (1, 1, -1), a((1, 2, 3)) = (1, 0, 1), a((3, 1, -1)) = (2, 1, 0). I know how to solve such tasks for $a\in(\mathbb R^3)$, but I really get stucked with finite field. How to solve tasks of such type?

Comment: Do you mean 'how many'?

Comment: Sorry, it was a misprint.